# How to overwrite modules by default with DRUSH?

Tags: drush

I am using a module list from Drupal 7 to populate a Drupal 8 site.

Some modules are now included in core, so there are a lot of confirm overwrite messages like this:

```
 Install location C:\drupal-8.0.1//modules/imagecache_actions already exists. Do
you want to overwrite it? (y/n):
```

What is the command for default Y or N ?

Now I use this command:

```
 drush en module -y
```

But I would like to set default answer to "overwrite yes" if module is already enabled or already exists and downloaded so I don't have to manually enter Y everytime

Answer (score 0):

**Overwrite**
Allows the project to be installed in a directory that is not empty. If not specified this is treated as FALSE, Drush make sets an error when the directory is not empty. If specified TRUE, Drush make will continue and use the existing directory. Useful when adding extra files and folders to existing folders in libraries or module extensions.

```
projects:
  myproject:
    overwrite: TRUE
```

Comment: This answer is for Drush make. The question was for Drush pm-enable.

Comment: Yes indeed, this is for simple drush command to install modules, looking for the equivalent of overwrite options in FTP